# Counting problem (Combinatorics/Discrete math)

Tags: combinatorics

A restaurant has a menu containing 12 starters, 22 main courses.

a) 7 friends visit. 5 have a starter, all 7 have a main course. How many ways to do this?
- My answer: (12)5 x (22)7 (i.e. 12x11x...x8 x 22x21x...x16)

b) 8 people visit. They only order 8 main courses, and they share (so who orders what is irrelevant). How many ways?
- My answer: (22)8

c) 8 people consisting of 3 veg & 5 non-veg people. Of the 22 main courses, 7 are veg, 15 are non-veg.
As in b), they order 8 main courses to share, but must have **at least** 3 veg & **at least** 3 non-veg (they want 8 different courses). How many ways?
- My answer: I'm thinking Inclusion-Exclusion, but not sure what to name the sets as. I was thinking (22)8 minus # ways to choose 0 & 0, 1 & 0, ... 3 & 2, 2 & 3 but this seems too complicated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please re-tag, this is combinatorics, not discrete mathematics.

Comment: @pj241 (12)5 is 12 choose 5?

Comment: In a), you made the implicit assumption that they order different things. Even if we make that (unreasonable) assumption, the answer is not quite right. There are $\binom{7}{5}$ ways to choose **who** has a starter. Then the actual starters they order can be chosen in $12^5$ ways, an the mains in $22^7$ ways. If we assume distinctness, the answer would be yours multiplied by $\binom{7}{5}$. In b), if they order different courses the answer is $\binom{22}{8}$. If not necessarily different, use Stars and Bars.

Comment: @bobbym no, (12)5 = 12x11x10x9x8

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks, that helped a lot!

Comment: You are welcome.